# What does <x:div> mean in HTML?

Tags: html, xml, xhtml

In HTML, you can denote a simple element tag as such. `<div></div>`. But I am seeing in code something like, `<x:div></div>`.

Can anyone tell me roughly what that 'x' means? I can't seem to find information on it simply because I don't know how to describe it properly.

Comment: it's an xml [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace)

Comment: Where do you see this code? In XML (which XHTML relies on) the x would mean that you define a div element within a namespace x. This namespace needs to be declared with an uniq identifier before.

Comment: You must be using a third party library that preprocesses HTML before rendering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of syntax is very rare in HTML, but occurs pretty commonly in XML (XML and HTML are very similar languages, both based on a standard called [SGML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language)). In your example, "x" is an example of a namespace.

Namespaces are used in SGML-based languages for ensuring that two unrelated types of elements don't have naming conflicts. You can read more about them [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) (or, if that link ever goes dead, search for "xml namespaces").

EDIT: Upon further consideration, what you probably are looking at is an example of [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT). XSLT is a way of styling XML documents to transform them into other formats such as HTML. [Here's a good intro to XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/).